# Send input to all clients SocketServer Android

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am trying to make a Server that sends back to all connected clients any input it has received. I am using a Service that on create it starts a thread.

```
public void onCreate() 
{       
    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}
```

Here is the Thread

```
 public void run() 
        {
        try 
            {                                           
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            while (true) 
                {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    mclients = new Vector<Socket>();
                    mclients.add(client);
                    boolean finished = false;   
                    try                             
                        {
                        for(int i=0; i<mclients.size(); i++)        {
                            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(mclients.get(i).getInputStream());
                            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(mclients.get(i).getOutputStream());
                            // Print a message:
                            System.out.println("Client from : " + mclients.get(i).getInetAddress() + " port " + mclients.get(i).getPort());
                            // now get the input from the socket...
                            while(!finished) 
                            {
                                String st = in.readLine();
                                // Send the same back to client
                                out.println(st);
                                // Write it to the screen as well
                                System.out.println(st);
                                // If the input was "quit" then exit...
                                if (st.equals("quit")) { finished = true; System.out.println("Thread exiting..."); }
                            }
                                                                    }
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {}});                                  

                        }
                    catch (final Exception e) {handler.post(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {}});e.printStackTrace();}
                }
```

It works only for the client who sent the input. The input is not echoed back to all clients.Can anyone help me out with this.I think that my client code is wrong but i can't figured it out.Here is my client code:

```
public class Client extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText serverIp;
private static EditText data;
private TextView receivedata, answer1 ,answer2, answer3, answer4;
private Button connectPhones, send;
private String serverIpAddress = "";
private boolean connected = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);


    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    receivedata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    answer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtans1);
    answer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtans2);
    answer3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtans3);
    answer4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtans4);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(this);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {        
        if(v == send)
        {
            if (!connected)
            {
                serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
                if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) 
                {
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
                                }  
    public class ClientThread implements Runnable 
    {           
        String line;
        String[] answers = new String[5];
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable()    {
                public void run()   {
                   receivedata.setText( line );
                   //answer1.setText( answers[1] ); 
                   //answer2.setText( answers[2] ); 
                   //answer3.setText( answers[3] ); 
                   //answer4.setText( answers[4] ); 
                                    }
                                                        };
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: SENDING...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);
                connected = true;
                while(connected) 
                {
                    try 
                    {                           
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream()));                        
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());                                            
                    out.println(data.getText());                                 
                    line = in.readLine();       // read server
                    System.out.println("Echo: " + line);                        
                    handler.post(updateUI);
                    in.close();                     // Close stream
                    out.close();
                    }                       
                    catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);                             
                        }                                       
                        connected = false;
                }
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            }   catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);

                        }
        }        
        }}
```

-----EDIT------
Should i use a different thread for handling the clients or it would be a problem? And how should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are also instantiating ServerSocket itself within the loop.
you dont need to create a new serversocket for each connection, you only need one server socket then loop to accept connections and add connections to the (already instantiated in oncreate()) list. see the example below.

if this still doesn't work then we'll have to see rest of the code aswell. 
And i like to stress again on that this will not always work on android, as android can also kill your service and app to grab resources, and everytime wifi, 3g or whatever is on the phone looses connection your socket is likely to fail.

```
ArrayList<Socket> mCLients;
ServerSocket serverSocket;

public void onCreate() 
{       
    mCLients; = new ArrayList<Socke>();
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}
```

//.....

```
private Static void send(final String message){
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        for(Socket socket: mClients){
        // send message to the socket
        }
    }
    thread.start();
}
```

//....

```
public void run(){

            while (true) 
                {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    mclients.add(client);
                    //Read client input
                    MyService.send(message);
                }  

 }
```

Note this code is no way the best way, i am just giving you a quick example on how you should approach this.

Comment: The serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT); is outside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

By having a quick (very quick) look i believe your problem seems to be the following code inside the run()

mclients = new Vector();

you are creating a new vector object every-time your program runs.

i suggest to move this out of the run(), and make sure your mClients is created before you start the thread that listens for incoming connections.

However note: running server on the android phone is a bad idea! mobile phones have limitations such as limited battery life, processing, memory and inconsistent internet connectivity, there are other ways to handle such communication. for example consider messaging, c2dm, xmpp etc.

Comment: Nope it didn't work. I made mclients static, but it didn;t work either